# How to find the magnitude of the maximum transverse acceleration of a given point on a string?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, waves

A thin string 2.50 m in length is stretched with a tension of 90.0 N between two supports. When the string vibrates in its first overtone, a point at an antinode of the standing wave on the string has an amplitude of 3.50 cm and a maximum transverse speed of 24.5 m/s.

How would I find the mass of the string and the magnitude of the maximum transverse acceleration of this point on the string. I'm pretty confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let its length be $L$ and the tension be denoted as $T$.

 Since it is the first overtone,
$L=\lambda$
Also, let the amplitude of any point on the string is $A$ and its angular frequency is $\omega$,
Max. speed of any point $=A\omega= v_{max}$
$\omega=\frac{v_{max}}{A}= 700 s^{-1}$ 
The speed of the wave is,
$v=\sqrt{\frac{T}{\mu}}=\frac{\omega}{k}=\frac{\lambda\omega}{2\pi}$ 
Hence,
$\mu=\frac{4\pi^2T}{\lambda^2\omega^2}=1.16 \times 10^{-3}$Kgm$^{-1}$
Hence,
$\boxed{m=\mu L=2.9}$ g
Also, maximum acceleration = $\boxed{A\omega^2 = 17,150}$ ms$^{-2}$.